# Prevent FOUC using jQuery UI Accordion and javascript loading in body

Tags: javascript, html5boilerplate, jquery-ui-accordion, fouc

My current problem is that my webpage suffers from FOUC using the jQuery UI Accordion plugin and javascript being loaded at the end of my html-body-tag. When I include the javascript in the head everything loads just fine. html5boilerplate recommends [putting all the javascript at the end of the body-tag](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html) to avoid slow page loading.

I also tried to `display: none` the accordion and `show()` it on document ready after I initialized the accordion but that is not satisfying, too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did have the problem. Reading that article -> http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content helped a lot.